# How to create a DOM element and declare it with an ID in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

im trying to sign in with signInWithPhoneNumber from firebaseAuth for flutter web, but i want to change the default reCaptcha to an inline widget , according to the documentation say this: *To add an inline widget, specify a DOM element ID to the container argument of the RecaptchaVerifier instance*

but im kind of new in dart and flutter so i dont know how to do that , is there a widget that i can create so i can add an ID and make it part of DOM?? .... i add a pic of the documentation of what firebaseAuth says:
[image]

Comment: Did you found the answer from anywhere else? If so please share it.

Comment: no, nobody help me at this, so i disable sms functionality on web, so now that flutter web is on stable i really hope flutter community will be eager to help others

Comment: I  am facing the same problem. Also, after hosting my flutter web app, the authentication service doesn't work, while it was working fine in localhost. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game but I hope this might be helpful someone else...

Insert a div in your .html with your targeted id

```
  <div id="recaptchaDOM"></div>
```

Ensure it is the same id indicated in your dart code under 'container'

```
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456', RecaptchaVerifier(
  container: 'recaptchaDOM',
  size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
  theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
));
```

You might want to change the z-index of your recaptchaDOM div so that it appears in front of your flutter layer. And upon verification, call a function in dart to js to remove all children of your recaptchaDOM div.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this problem too. In the end, I decided not to use the inline variant. The default settings work (it has a few bugs but better than nothing).

```dart
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('<PHONE>', RecaptchaVerifier(
  size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.normal,
  theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
));
```

@lolerla seems to be right about the implementation. But that seems like a lot of work to me. The inline variant should come out of the box too in my opinion.